# Scheme built-in to check list containment

Tags: list, scheme

In Python I can do "x in list" to see if the list contains x. Is there any equivalent built-in in Scheme to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_428), and the R6RS [standard library for lists](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_226)
define `memq`, `memv`, and `member`
which can be used for that purpose.

Comment: It's not just in an SRFI, but also in R5RS (which is implemented by all decent implementations) http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_428

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have corrected the references in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In PLT Scheme, one has

```
(member whatever list)
(memv whatever list)
(memq whatever list)
```

from the SRFI which use, respectively, `equal?`, `eqv?`, and `eq?` to test for equality.  There are also a number of other library functions related to searching in lists:

[PLT Scheme list reference](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/pairs.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
(define (contains? l i)
  (if (empty? l) #f
      (or (eq? (first l) i) (contains? (rest l) i))))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no list built-in predicate that will do that for you. It's extremely easy to define a lambda or a macro to do just that though.