# Scheme Recursion Loop Incorrect Values and Variable Binding

Tags: recursion, data-binding, scheme, racket

I started a question here about a hangman game I am working on.

[Recursive Scheme Function Value Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134917/recursive-scheme-function-value-error)

I feel that the hangman portion is confusing people from my real issue and question. My problem is, I call various defined functions from within my recursion loop and get incorrect values. When I call these same function by themselves (not in a recursive loop) they work as expected. I know it is either something I am overlooking or a variable binding issue is going on that I need a workaround for.

First here a reproduction of the problem code:

```
(define (recurse a_list a_number)
       (cond ((= a_number 0)
                 (display "Zero Condition.")
              )
             (else
                 (display "\n\n")
                 (display-list a_list ",")
                 (display "\n")
                 (display (car a_constant))
                 (display "\n")
                 (display "If the above letter is in the list, result should be true\n")
                 (display (contains? a_list (car a_constant)))
                 (display "\n")
                  (display "Enter a letter:")
                  (recurse (cons (symbol->string (read)) a_list) (- a_number 1))
              )
        )
   )
```

Here are my definitions used inside the recursive loop:

```
(define (display-list a_list separater)

   (if (null? a_list)

      (display "")

      (begin 

         (display (car a_list))

         (if (null? (cdr a_list))

            (display "")

            (display separater))

         (display-list (cdr a_list) separater)

      )

   )

)

(define (contains? list item)
  ;(display "\n")
  ;(display list)
  ;(display "\n")
  ;(display item)
  ;(display "\n")
  (cond ((empty? list)
       #f
     )
    ((eq? (first list) item)
       #t
     )
    (else
       (contains? (rest list) item)
     )
   )
 )


(define a_constant '("n" "o" "t" "w" "o" "r" "k" "i" "n" "g"))
(define test_li_1 '("n" "b"))
(define test_li_2 '("a" "b"))
```

This is what I ran:

```
> (contains? a_constant (car test_li_1))

#t
> (contains? a_constant (car test_li_2))

#f
```

It works as expected.

When I run the recursive Loop this is what I get:

```
> (recurse test_li_2 2)


a,b
n
If the above letter is in the list, result should be true
#f

Enter a letter:n


n,a,b
n
If the above letter is in the list, result should be true
#f
```

In my mind, the first output is correct, but the second one is not.

When I run with test_li_1 it always evaluates to true which, it should since 'n' is always in my a_list. What I have put together through several tests, is the recursive function keeps using my initially passed in list and does not use the appended version for function calls, which is not what I want it to do. I also think that is not how it should work right? Shouldn't my passed in value be used and not a value from several recursive levels up? I'm testing this all in Dr. Racket with #lang racket in case that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem reported occurs because you're using [`eq?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq~3f%29%29) to test for string equality. From the documentation:

> `(eq? v1 v2) → boolean?` : Return `#t` if `v1` and `v2` refer to the same object, `#f` otherwise.

So you see, `eq?` is testing for *identity*, not for *equality*. For that, you should use [`string=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string~3d~3f%29%29) or [`equal?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29). Modify the `contains?` procedure as follows, and it'll work:

```
(define (contains? list item)
  (cond 
    ((empty? list) #f)
    ((string=? (first list) item) #t)
    (else (contains? (rest list) item))))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `(symbol->string (read))` and enter in `a`, you get a *fresh string* "a". This is a new string object that is *not eq?* to any "a" in your program. Try this to see the problem:

```
(eq? (symbol->string (read)) "a")
```

If you enter in `a`, this will output `#f` because the two string items are separate objects. You've run afoul of *string interning*. All instances of "a" written in your source code are stored as references to one object upon compilation, so `(eq? "a" "a")` will evaluate to true. When you `(read)` input as strings, those strings will be freshly created objects and won't be equal to any other strings. There are two ways you can fix this:

1. Use [`string=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string%3D%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._string%7E3d%7E3f%29%29) for comparison instead of [`eq?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=eq%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._eq%7E3f%29%29) (as in Oscar's answer)
2. Use lists of characters instead of lists of single-character strings, e.g. `'(#\a #\b #\c)` is the string "abc". From the [Racket documentation of characters:](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html)

   > Two characters are eqv? if they correspond to the same scalar value. For each scalar value less than 256, character values that are eqv? are also eq?

Letter characters (a-z and A-Z) have values less than this in Racket's Unicode encoding, so any letter characters you `read` in will not run afoul of the `eq?` issue. This brings up another point - you should be sanitizing your input from `read`. The `read` procedure is *not* guaranteed to return a string, in particular if I enter in 1 instead of a string, it returns the number 1, not the string "1". You should add some logic to handle bad input, or this will crash your program.

Comment: I feel so silly! I knew it was most likely something simple. Thank you and thank you @oscarlopez I just happened to see Jacks answer first.

Comment: @MrJman006 The difference is, Óscar's answer is correct and Jack's answer is more questionable (I will write a comment explaining this in a minute, along with a downvote :-)). I would therefore recommend you accept Óscar's answer instead.

Comment: Now, here's my objections to this answer: 1. Two instances of `"a"` in the source code are _not_ guaranteed to be coalesced or interned. Implementations are free, but not required, to do so (for example, Guile returns false for `(eq? "a" "a")`). It's not wise to depend on this behaviour.

Comment: 2. `symbol->string` is not guaranteed to return a fresh string. In fact, the way R5RS and R7RS is worded, if an implementation uses backing strings for symbols, `symbol->string` is certainly allowed to return the same backing string when called with the same symbol. (For implementations that don't use backing strings for symbols, then of course `symbol->string` is more likely to return a fresh string.)

Comment: 3. `(eq? '(#\a #\b #\c) '(#\a #\b #\c))` is false in many implementations (including Racket). Implementations are allowed, but not required, to coalesce literal data, but in practice, implementations coalesce atomic data only, if at all.

Comment: Since the `eq?` comparison is coming up in his `contains?` function, then actually if he were using character lists what would be evaluated is `(contains? '(#\a #\b #\c) #\a)`, so the point about `(eq? '(#\a #\b #\c) '(#\a #\b #\c))` seems unrelated. My other points weren't also about what the spec says should happen, but rather explanations for Racket's implementation details that were giving rise to the behavior. Your comments about the language spec are all correct though.

Comment: I see your reasoning. I have changed the answer.

Comment: I still really appreciate the answer Jack!